# using display:table-cell with position:fixed

Tags: html, css

I made one container `<div>`,and inside that one there are two `<div>`'s:
one is width 80% and the other is 20% and need to be `position:fixed`.

For some reason the total width of the container `<div>` is longer then the browser window.

once I remove the `position:fixed` on the right `<div>` everything is in order but I do need that `<div>` to be `position:fixed`.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="leftSummary"></div>
    <div class="rightTasks"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.leftSummary {
    width: 80%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.rightTasks {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 275px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: what is the resolution of your screen? it could be that 20% is smaller than the 275px of your min-width.

Comment: I want the right div to be 20% or min-width:275 any way.

Comment: yes, but thats not my question. because if you use a `min-width:275px` on a screen that is 1200px wide.. 20% of that would be 240px (smaller than the min-width). and that means, that the screen cant be, AND 80% AND the `min-width:275px`. Because than you get a screen width of 1235px (35px to wide)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl May I ask why you added `height` and `background` to all three rules? As long as I see in revisions OP never mention or hint that.

Comment: Sorry, bout that... I must have posted my additions. :-(

Answer (score 4):

There is a basic issue here. Once you set `position: fixed` on `.rightTasks`, the display property is computed to `block` instead of `table-cell`.

This will change the layout accordingly and you need to rethink your markup.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Also, elements with `position: fixed` are positioned with respect to the view port, not the block element that contains them.  Therefore, the 20% width is with respect to the view port and not the `.test` parent.

If you inspect the `.rightTasks` element, you will see that the width is 20% of the view port width and not 20% of the table width.  If you set the table width to 50%, the effect is more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `min-width`.

Live [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6wUVW/)

**EDIT**

If you want to use `min-width` with `position: fixed` , you should use `top` and `right` css. If you dont want to encounter issue that is by browser, you should use **[reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**

Live [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6wUVW/1/)

Comment: I remove the min-width:275px,but still noting is changing.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Did you look at first live demo? In it does not seem a problem.